# Block user for half hour if he exceeded Throttling limits in one minute ( Laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm using Throttling  and I notice you can allow number requests per specific  amount of time  but I'm trying to do something differnt

if I set  Throttling  60:1

so it's allowed to send 60 request every one minute

But is it possible to make it like this Throttling   60:1:30

like if the user made 60 request in one minute then block him for 30 minutes

Answer (score -1):

Customizing the throttle middleware

If we want to limit it to 5 attempts per minute.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'throttle:5'], function () {
    Route::get('people', function () {
        return Person::all();
    });
});
```

And if we want to change it so that, if someone hits the limit, they can't try again for another 10 minutes.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'throttle:5,10'], function ()     {
    Route::get('people', function () {
        return Person::all();
    });
});
```

Update

you need to add a date time flag in db banned_at and set it when the rate limit is reached. set that date time by adding 30 min to current date time, and compare it when when user accesses route with the help of middleware. when the user accesses within 30 min of rate limit reaching, the date time in db banned_at will be greater than current time, and you can block him in that case.

Update

there is another way, see if you can set $key variable in RateLimiter class here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php#L38 , i could not find way to set it

Hope this helps you.

Comment: No  this means throttle:5,10   he can make 5 requests every 10 minutes  correct ?

Comment: ok I want to block him for 30 minutes if he  made 5 requests in 10 minutes   I hope it's clear now

Comment: Oh, then refer this https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-ban-revoke-user-functionality-in-laravel-5-example-example.html . you need to add a date time flag in db banned_at and set it when the rate limit is reached. set that date time by adding 30 min to current date time, and compare it when when user accesses route with the help of middleware

Comment: there is another way, see if you can set $key variable in RateLimiter class here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php#L38 , i could not find way to set it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but ban provider is  totally different from throttle. this key in second link I believe it linked somehow to user ip  so you can set the limits on him you must not change it.   I opened this question just to know if someone have additional code for throttle

Comment: i don't think what you say is possible, ban provider is the way laravel would have implemented this in throttle but it has not done it, instead they are automatically setting $key to the amount remaining for the throttle from the time you reached the rate limit.